# JAVA: How can I download an HTML file from a site that requires cookies enabled?

Tags: java, html, cookies

I'm trying to download an HTML file from a site. I'm using the following simple method:

```
 URL url = new URL("here goes the link to the html file");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
 String htmlfile = "";
 String temp;
 while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
       htmlfile+= temp;
 }
```

The problem is that I get the following String in the htmlfile variable:

```
The installation of ... requires the acceptance of a cookie by your browser    
software.    The cookie is used to ensure that you and only you are 
able to access information ....
```

In other words, I need to somewhat enable cookies when opening a stream from the url. Is it possible to achieve this by using URL or do I need a different method? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`addRequestProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to set a cookie on a [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) object, e.g.

```
URL url = new URL("here goes the link to the html file");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "here goes the cookie");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

If the cookie isn't known beforehand, but is set by a reply to a previous HTTP request, then one can use [`getHeaderFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields%28%29) etc on the `URLConnection` instance representing the previous HTTP exchange to retrieve the cookie.

Comment: True, but if the site requires you to accept (and retransmit) cookies, then a little more work i required.

Comment: That's right. You can read the cookie sent by the server by looking at the `Set-Cookie` header using `getHeaderFields()` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a good library like Apache HttpComponents

http://hc.apache.org/index.html

it takes care of cookie-management for you.